# Java - Convert classes

Tags: java, mapping, converters

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}
```

and

```
public class Buyer {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
}
```

I want both classes to convert to a the following class:

```
public class CustomerDTO {
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
}
```

I cannot use a common interface for the classes or something. Is there a way I can convert Customer and Buyer both to a Customer DTO class with a single converter class?

Comment: Given the circumstances - no. You'd either have two converters or you pull a common interface. Well, of course you can write your own hackish way of doing it via reflection or `instanceof`, if it's so necessary, but I would not recommend

Comment: Why can't you use an interface? It would be simple to define a `convertableToCustomerDTO` interface and implement one converter.

Comment: extend both classes from CustomerDTO.

Comment: Because of generated code, I cannot change Customer or Buyer

Comment: @AliMomeni That's bad advice. It completely defeats the purpose of using a DTO.

Comment: i understand what you mean he can use mapper classes to convert those classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert (map) two classes (`Customer`, `Buyer`) to a third one (`CustomerDTO`) with a single converter class because there is no common type (i.e. an interface) shared by your two classes. Java does not use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) so you cannot rely to the fact that your classes *look similar*. Compiler does not see that.

Having that said, you can at least automate the generation of the mappers you need. An option would be [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). In your case, mapping would be straightforward (based on [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#basic-mappings)):

```java
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {

    CustomerDto toCustomerDto(Customer customer);

    CustomerDto toCustomerDto(Buyer buyer);
}
```

MapStruct is a compile time dependency: it will generate the mappers for you at compile time, so you can review them.

---

Thanks [Royal Bg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2216380/royal-bg) for the suggestion to use method overloading (`toCustomerDto`) for a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Java doesn't support duck typing normally, but you can enforce it with reflection. If you receive `Object` as a param, you can check whether it has certain fields or methods. However, I would not suggest that at all, just mentioning it. Since the only good way is with two converters, I would use some kind of polymorphism here - method overloading. Both methods to be named something like `toCustomerDto` so you don't need to type different function names when you get one or the another type to convert.

Comment: Well said @RoyalBg. I agree that reflection would be a not-so-clean way to solve this so I deliberately did not mention (but I did up-vote your comments :) )

Comment: Good explanation, especially the fact that *duck typing* is mentioned. With duck typing, OP would perhaps not even have the problem they're currently facing.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that MapStruct supports polymorphism @RoyalBg so I used different methods. It would indeed be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @TasosP. I have only used it in Kotlin, but it should not be different, all my functions are named `map(type)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use model mapper, for example checkout this http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/

Comment: How would model mapper help here without declaring two mapping delegates?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly define delagetes, mapper resolves variables automatically by their type and name

Comment: Yes, this is the case when type and name are equal in both source and target. Despite the fact the question has this as an example, if you rely on this magic, the conversion will soon fail once you have different naming for instance.

I would rather suggest to solve the problem where `Buyer` and `Customer` have both equal fields, but they do not match in `CustomerDTO` as it would be a more generic case

Comment: That's indeed the probleem. `Buyer` and `Customer` always have equal fields. But `CustomerDTO` can have different fields.

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample code you can add this to your DTO code for both Customer and Buyer

```
public UserDTO(Cutomer user) {
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.login = user.getLogin();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.authorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(Authority::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```